# how to properly insert <div> with <tr> inside a table?

Tags: html, html-table

I've searched online and I can't find an answer, so I'm going to ask this question.

The new data will always be formatted in the following and will be populated in id="content"

```
<tr>
   <td>name</td>
   <td>age</td>
   <td>gender</td>
</tr>
```

I read you need to have `<div>` inside a `<td>` if you're going to put `<div>` inside a `<table>`. Right now, the format is not correct. All of the new data are in column one instead of each of them in each row.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>gender</th>
   </tr>
   <td>
      <div id="contents">
         <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>male</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Jess</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>female</td>
         </tr>
      </div>
   <td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

re-reading your structure you most likely need

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>gender</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="contents">
     <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>male</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Jess</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>female</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Original answer**

You can't have `tr` as direct children of a `div`.

You need to use a table

Either

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>gender</th>
   </tr>
   <td>
      <table id="contents">
       <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>male</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Jess</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>female</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
   <td>
</table>
```

or

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>gender</th>
   </tr>
   <td>
      <div id="contents">
       <table>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>male</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jess</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>female</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </div>
   <td>
</table>
```

Comment: <thead> and <tbody> WORKS!I learned something today. If I want to append new data to table, I should append them to <tbody> instead of <div>. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want the table to be inside the div completely, and all the new data be in a corresponding row, like this:

```
<div id="contents">
  <table>
     <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>gender</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>male</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Jess</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>female</td>
     </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

Right now the format is wrong because of you are trying to add whole data into a single cell (`<td>` element) which isn't right way to do.